# Bad: Error in FragmentSupport android studios

Tags: android, kotlin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32ezf.png)I have an error on line 159 and I don't know why, the error occurs at run time, it has to do with the fragments, I'm new to this and I don't have a clear idea of what is happening. thank you

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1844)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1884)
at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:329)
at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:294)
at androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment.show(DialogFragment.java:260)
at com.rockstone.mototaxappdriver.activities.MapActivity.showModalBooking(MapActivity.kt:159)
at com.rockstone.mototaxappdriver.activities.MapActivity.listenerBooking$lambda$5(MapActivity.kt:174)
at com.rockstone.mototaxappdriver.activities.MapActivity.$r8$lambda$SF-3tZlg33sAScxiUXAqT7VjYu0(Unknown Source:0)
at com.rockstone.mototaxappdriver.activities.MapActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda4.onEvent(Unknown Source:4)

I have no idea what is going on